# How would I interpret a LPWSTR as an out parameter in a Win32 call?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to call a Win32 function with the following signature:

```
HRESULT GetDefaultStartupFlags(
     [out]  DWORD *pdwStartupFlags,
     [out, size_is(*pcchHostConfigFile)] LPWSTR pwzHostConfigFile,
     [in, out]  DWORD *pcchHostConfigFile);
```

(function reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569964%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

I am very confused how to interpret a "LPWSTR" that is also an [out] parameter.  Does this mean that I am expected to pass a LPWSTR that is pointing to pre-allocated space that will be overwritten?  If this is true, how do I interpret "size_is(...)" directive for knowing how large the buffer should be, and how do you allocate an empty WSTR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of `wchar_t` for LPWSTR
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx)
Allocation as usual (fixed size, or malloc in C / new in C++)
The result is a file path, so it will be stored as UTF16 (as usual in Windows).

The last parameter of your function is for passing the allocated length.
As stated in the docs, you can pass 0 to get the expected size
(to allocate enough and then call the function again)

Answer (score 2):

Passing `NULL` for the 2nd parameter causes the required size to be returned in the 3rd.

```
DWORD flgs, sz;
HRESULT hr = GetDefaultStartupFlags(&flgs, NULL, &sz);
if (hr != S_OK) { }
WSTR config[sz]; // or malloc or new ...
hr = GetDefaultStartupFlags(&flgs, config, &sz);
if (hr != S_OK) { }
```